# Why RcppArmadillo's fastLmPure produces NA's in output but fastLm doesn't?

Tags: c++, r, regression, rcpp, armadillo

I use rolling regression in R quite a lot and my initial setup is something like:

```
dolm <- function(x) coef(lm(x[,1] ~ x[,2] + 0, data = as.data.frame(x)))
rollingCoef = rollapply(someData, 100, dolm)
```

Above example works perfectly, except it is slow if you have a lot of iterations.

To speed it up I've decided to experiment with `Rcpp` package.

First I substituted `lm` with `fastLm`, result is a bit faster but still slow. So that pushed me to attempt to write the entire rolling regression's coefficients function in c++ as for loop and than integrate it in R with Rcpp help.

So I've changed original RcppArmadillo's function `fastLm` to this:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]] 

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

List rollCoef(const arma::mat& X, const arma::colvec& y, double window ) {

    double cppWindow = window - 1;
    double matRows = X.n_rows;
    double matCols = X.n_cols - 1;

    arma::mat coef( matRows - cppWindow, X.n_cols);   // matrix for estimated coefficients

    //for loop for rolling regression.
    for( double i = 0 ; i < matRows - cppWindow ; i++  )
    {
        coef.row(i) = arma::trans(arma::solve(X( arma::span(i,i + cppWindow), arma::span(0,matCols)) , y.rows(i,i + cppWindow)));
    }

  return List::create(_["coefficients"] = coef);
}
```

and than download it to R with `sourceCpp(file=".../rollCoef.cpp")`

So it's much faster than `rollapply` and it worked fine on small examples, but than I applied it to ~200000 observations of data it produced ~half of NA's in output, in the same time `rollapply`/`fastLm` combination didn't produce any.

So here I need some help. What is wrong with my function? Why are there NA's in my function output, and no NA's in `rollapply`/`fastLm`, however, if I understand right, them both based on `arma::solve`? Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is reproducible code:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(RcppArmadillo)
require(zoo)
require(repmis)
myData <- source_DropboxData(file = "example.csv", 
                              key = "cbrmkkbssu5bn96", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

## in order to use my custom function "rollCoef" you should download it to R. 
## The c++ code is presented above in the main question.
## Download it where you want as "rollCoef.cpp" and then download it to R with:

sourceCpp(file=".../rollCoeff.cpp"). # there should be your actual path. 

myCoef = rollCoef(as.matrix(myData[,2]),myData[,1],260)

summary(unlist(myCoef)) # 80923 NA's

dolm = function(x) coef(fastLmPure(as.matrix(x[,2]), x[,1]))

myCoef2 = rollapply(myData, 260, dolm, by.column = FALSE)

summary(myCoef2) # 80923 NA's

dolm2 = function(x) coef(fastLm(x[,1] ~ x[,2] + 0, data = as.data.frame(x)))

myCoef3 = rollapply(myData, 260, dolm2, by.column = FALSE)

summary(myCoef3) # !!! No NA's !!!

head(unlist(myCoef)) ; head(unlist(myCoef2)) ; head(myCoef3)
```

So the output of my function is identical to output of RcppArmadillo's `fastLmPure` combined with `rollapply` and them both produce NA's, but `rollapply` with `fastLm` does not. As I understand, for example from [HERE](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp) and [HERE](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/R/fastLm.R) `fastLm` is basically calling to `fastLmPure`, but why is there no NA's in the third method than? Is there some additional capabilities in `fastLm` that prevent NA's that I didn't spotted?

Comment: How about including a sample of your data set?

Comment: It would be really nice to have a MWE to look at. I can't get your first two lines to work even with simple data

Comment: I updated the question with code sample

Comment: You *changed the entire question* which entirely inappropriate.  My answer below now looks out of place.  *If you have a new question. ask a new question*.

Comment: Sorry for that. Next time I will do so. But for now would you please answer here for time saving? Or do you insist that I create a new one?

Comment: Create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire package [RcppRoll](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/index.html) to do just that custom rolling -- and you should be able to extend it and its `rollit()` function to do rolling `lm()` as well.

Comment: I know about RcppRoll and use it in some cases, but custom code may be faster and not to mention additional practical benefits from writing your own code ;)